# Neovim - coc-html keeps inner html head and body tags indented

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, filetype-html

When I create `filename.html` file and type enter after the `html` tag, `coc-html` keeps inner content of `html` tag indented:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

The expected behavior is:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
</html>
```

I use `coc.nvim` together with its `coc-html` and `coc-htmldjango` plugins. Neovim version is 0.9.4.

Here are my config files: https://codeberg.org/lester29/neovim_config

I have the same behavior in Visual Studio Code